# Place file contents in email body in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that checks hard drive space on a group of servers, sends out an email, and it attaches a file containing the output contents. Is there a way to place the contents of the file in the body itself? I would like the file contents to be able to be seen at a glance in the email. The content would be the registered variable, `result`.

The current tasks:

```
---
- name: Check for output file
  stat:
    path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
  register: stat_result
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Create file if it does not exist
  file:
    path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
    state: touch
    mode: '0666'
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Check hard drive info
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  shell: cat /etc/hostname; echo; df -h | egrep 'Filesystem|/dev/sd'
  register: result
- debug: var=result.stdout_lines

- local_action: lineinfile line={{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }} dest=/tmp/ansible_output.txt
    - name: Email Result
      mail:
        host: some_email_host
        port: some_port_number
        username: my_username
        password: my_password
        to:
          - first_email_address
          - second_email_address
          - third_email_address
        from: some_email_address
        subject: My Subject
        body: <syntax for file contents in body here> <--- What is the syntax?
        attach:
          /tmp/ansible_output.txt
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost

- name: Remove Output File
  file:
    path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
    state: absent
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

**Edit**: I tried

```
body: "{{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }}"
```

but it only sends me the output of the first host in the group.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I created a directory, `files`, and sent the output to a file in that directory using the `{{ role_path }}` variable. In the body portion of the email task, I used the `lookup` plugin to grab the contents of the file.

Here is the updated playbook with the original lines commented out:

```
---
- name: Check for output file
  stat:
    #path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt"
  register: stat_result
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Create file if it does not exist
  file:
    #path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt"
    state: touch
    mode: '0666'
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == False
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Check hard drive info
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  shell: cat /etc/hostname; echo; df -h | egrep 'Filesystem|/dev/sd'
  register: result
- debug: var=result.stdout_lines

#- local_action: lineinfile line={{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }} dest=/tmp/ansible_output.txt
- local_action: lineinfile line={{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }} dest="{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt"

- name: Email Result
  mail:
    host: some_email_host
    port: some_port_number
    username: my_username
    password: my_password
    to:
      - first_email
      - second_email
      - third_email
    from: some_email_address
    subject: Ansible Disk Space Check Result
    #body: "{{ result.stdout_lines | to_nice_json }}"
    body: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt') }}"
    #attach:
      #/tmp/ansible_output.txt
    attach:
      "{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Remove Output File
  file:
    #path: /tmp/ansible_output.txt
    path: "{{ role_path }}/files/ansible_output.txt"
    state: absent
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Now, my email contains the attachment, as well as the contents in the body, and I didn't have to change much in the playbook. :-)